# Sql query to execute & iterate through foreach

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have this query :-

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT MAS.CODE, 
               MAS.ENTRY_DATE, 
               IT.INDATE IN_DATE, 
               OT.INDATE OUT_DATE, 
               MAS.SHIFT_CODE, 
               MAS.SHIFT_FLAG, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN (IT.INDATE IS NOT NULL) AND (OT.INDATE IS NOT NULL) THEN 
                   CASE 
                     WHEN IT.INDATE = OT.INDATE THEN 
                       'FALSE' 
                     ELSE 
                       'OK' 
                   END 
                 ELSE  
                   'FAIL' 
               END AS VALID 
          FROM 
-------
```

I am generally using Entity Framework - Linq to manipulate data.

What is the way to directly run this query without converting it to Linq & then i want to iterate it in `foreach` loop.

Comment: add your script as a stored procedure and iterate through the returned dataset?

Comment: Why don't you want to convert to Linq?

Comment: @DavidG Any example how do i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get datatable as a result of stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249091/how-to-get-datatable-as-a-result-of-stored-procedure)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to iterate within your query you can use while loop
on the other end.
If you want iterate your returned data then you can use data table or data set.

By the way, why you don’t you want to use LINQ?

Comment: The sql query is too bigger & converting it to Linq is taking much time, so don't want to use linq.